# how to fix this error on react register with the following erros

Tags: reactjs

Why does this onSubmit function fail and gives me some errors?

```js
 onSubmit(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       const exercise={
           name: this.state.name,
           othername:this.state.othername,
           surname: this.state.surname,
           email: this.state.email,
           date: this.state.date,
           password: this.state.password,
       }

        console.log(exercise);
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/exercises/add', exercise)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data));

       window.Location= '/Profile';
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you able to add the errors to your question please.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props){
super()
this.state = {
    name: '',
    othername: '',
    surname: '',
    email:'',
    date: '',
    password: ''
 }
}

handleFieldChange = function(event){
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    })
}
onSubmit(e){
   e.preventDefault();

  if(this.state.name == '' || this.state.othername == '' || 
 this.state.surname == '') 
  {
       alert('All required fields')
       return false;
   }

   const exercise={
       name: this.state.name,
       othername:this.state.othername,
       surname: this.state.surname,
       email: this.state.email,
       date: this.state.date,
       password: this.state.password,
   }

    console.log(exercise);
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/exercises/add', exercise)
    .then(res => console.log(res.data));

   window.Location= '/Profile';
 }
```